# mac java setting error

Tags: java, macos

I was trying to run a program keep getting this error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/aliasi/classify/Classification
```

this is my .bash_profile file

```
 export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
 export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
 export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

I think something is not right about the classpath setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download `lingpipe-version.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: @tjjdg where is the jar located?

Comment: /Desktop/lingpipe-4.1.0/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar

Comment: @tjjdg so add it to: export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:/Desktop/lingpipe-4.1.0/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar

Comment: i did add export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:/Desktop/lingpipe-4.1‌​.0/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar to the ./bash_profile still same error...

Comment: @tjjdg how do you run the program? from commandline or in a webserver?

Comment: java -cp      sentimentDemo.jar:../../../lingpipe-4.0.jar PolarityBasic /Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR

Comment: @tjjdg try java -cp sentimentDemo.jar:/Desktop/lingpipe-4.1.0/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar ...