# Compiled JAVA project, can't make it work

Tags: java, mysql, json, eclipse, jar

got a problem, can't manage it to work for me right.

Completed my java project and i want it to compile and run for a test. I do compile it as "Jar file" (not runnable jar file). I compile it through Eclipse IDE.

I do not setup any more references in compiling settings, making everything stock. Once i compile it as "Server.jar" in my desktop i'm trying to run through console, because it's more like console program. I'm using macOS.

Using command : `java -jar Server.jar`
Error:

```
    Ervinass-MacBook-Air:Desktop Ervinas$ java -jar Server.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

What should i do?

It shouws class is not found if i'm right?

This : `org/json/simple/parser/ParseException` is not recognised.

What i have tried : `java -classpath ~/Documents/Java/Server/src/server/json-simple.jar -jar Server.jar`

As all of you see, i'm using json-simple.jar library, moreover i do use mysql library, so i guess later it will be the same problem with mysql library.

Any solution? Tired of getting it working now..

Comment: if you use `java -jar` and the classpath is added to the manifest file, the classpath in the command line is ignored

Comment: @Jens i don't use any manifest file, i guess it creates by default.

Comment: Yes it is. Look into your jar file and you will found the file. Take a look into it if there is a classpath entry

Comment: use: java -cp "json-simple.jar:Server.jar" com.your.main.Class

Comment: use below style 1. **java -cp "location of all supported jars" Main.class**  2. set all supported jars in the path variable and then you can simple call **java Main.class**

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254981/mac-java-setting-error

Comment: @elysrivero99 i tried : java -cp "~/Documents/Java/Server/src/server/json-simple.jar:Server.jar" server.Server , not working same error..

Comment: @Aman Checked it like 2 days ago, non of the solutions helped.

Comment: Please check updated comment link

Comment: @Ervinas34 have you tried to put all the dependencies jar into the same directory? And then use java -cp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mac java setting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254981/mac-java-setting-error)

Comment: @elysrivero99 it worked, getting other errors atm, but is it possible to do that there is only one .jar file it opens and it works, instead putting many library files in the same directory as .jar file?

By the way, thanks it worked!

Comment: @Aman Thanks a lot, but it's kinda solved now. :)

Comment: Look at how the .jar is built. It should have included all dependencies.

Comment: @Ervinas34, yes, you can create a single jar with all the dependencies inside (fat jat). This task can be done in a easier way using a dependencies manager (like maven).